# WEB Программа на Open Server работает, а на хостинге нет. Проблема с базами redbeanphp

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, hosting, redbeanphp

Написал программу скинул на сервер, а она выдает такое:

> Fatal error: Uncaught [42000] - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1286 Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' trace:
>
> 0 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(958):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('CREATE TABLE `u...', Array)
>
> 1 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(3455):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->Execute('CREATE TABLE `u...', Array)
>
> 2 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(5690):
>   RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->exec('CREATE TABLE `u...')
>
> 3 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(7505):
>   RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL->createTable('`users`')
>
> 4 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(7634):
>   RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->createTableIfNotExists(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean),
>   'users')
>
> 5 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(7233):
>   RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->storeBean(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean))
>
> 6 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(8310):
>   RedBeanPHP\Repository->store(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean))
>
> 7 /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php(10627):
>   RedBeanPHP\OODB->stor in /home/u585567935/public_html/APP/libs/rb.php
>   on line 720

Я так понимаю, что redbeanphp не может создать таблицы, но почему?
Может кто сталкивался с таким?
Спасибо.

Вот результат запросса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зарание скажу что бузу даных я создал.

Comment: тэг `sql-server` тут каким боком? сравните версии mysql на хостинге и на локалке

Comment: [Проблема в MySQL сервере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067254/1286-unknown-storage-engine-innodb). Выполните `Show engines;` и напишите выхлоп.

Comment: Я сделал запросс через php my admin изображение в вопросе